# "Save changes" and "Cancel" buttons on Careers edit page are misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

Screenshot should explain it just fine:

> [image]

This appears in the Careers edit profile page. Chrome 31.0.1650.63 but don't think it's browser specific.

Comment: Are you referring to this page: `careers.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/[user-id]`?

Comment: @Hynes yep that page indeed. From quick trial and error, removing the `vertical-align: bottom` from the CSS solve this, though not sure if it breaks other things on other pages. (it is applied to all buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. The issue arose from all `input, select, textarea` having a `margin: 5px 3px;`, yet all `input[type="submit"]` had the margins reset to `margin: 0;`. The 'Save Changes' button is a submit input. The 'Cancel' button isn't, thus the two buttons being misaligned. I resolved this by adding margin back to the submit input within this form only.

Comment: Cheers and thanks for the detailed response!